# How to draw ggplot of lm(log(y)~)and lm(y~x+x^2) in one plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

Using package ggplot2 and iris, I want to plot a scatterplot with the fitted regression lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length,color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula= 'Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width+I(Petal.Width^2)+SaleType+Petal.Width*Species', data=iris,
              aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length,color=Species))

**Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')**
```

I am thinking about the reason get this warning that I have two independent variables, but right now R can't read Species spliting up by colors in stat_smooth. How can I draw two lines which are sames as `plot(Petal.Width,fitted(fit))`. In addition, If I have another regression model fitted by same group of data, but log(y), `fit<-lm(log(Petal.Length)~Petal.Width+Species+Petal.Width*Species,data=iris).` Can I put the draws of two regression models into the same graph?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is appropriate to combine a transformed regression with a raw value on the same scale. Rather these should be plotted up on different figures. Using the `iris` dataset you can plot up the raw data like this:

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Width,color=Species))
```

Then log transform `Sepal.Width` into another variable:

```
iris$LogSepal.Width <- log(iris$Sepal.Width)
```

Then plot that transformed variable. I hope this helps.

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = LogSepal.Width)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", aes(x = Petal.Width, y = LogSepal.Width,color=Species))
```

Comment: Thank you! I got your idea of doing the log. But how can I draw the regression fit line of quadratic of variable and also with interaction.

Comment: I see. Usually it is better to run your models (if they get any complexity) outside of ggplot2. So I would run it like normal and then plot the model results.